# Laravel/PHP image upload filesize issue

Tags: php, image, laravel, upload

Whats the maximum file size for an image when building a gallery form, i just tried uploading 3 images of about 6mb each, and the application completely blanked out.

when i try to read the $_Files array of the $_POST data the out put is 
i.e

dd(Input::file('files'));

and my output is

array( length=0;
)

when i tried uploading files of lesser size, it worked perfectly, so i'm asking whats the best and preferred size to limit your images to when working with image uploads in laravel, i know i could adjust the max_file_size setting in the .ini file, but i like working with the defaults.

just incase of next time. thanks. and i would like to know why most importantly. 
if i am going to be adopting a pattern in my forms for handling images, then i want to keep in mind why i'm doing that.. thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Laravel. As you mentioned yourself, some settings should be changed: post_max_size & upload_max_filesize

Comment: interesting. thanks for that response.. i just needed clarity. should work with that.

Comment: Just in case anyone else encounters issues with uploading to images to laravel, as mentioned above the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size need to be changed. I also had to change the memory_limit and max_execution_time. My internet is slow, so it needs more time to upload. Got to keep that in mind for your users. So essentially even though I only want 8Mb max upload. I set it to like 64Mb and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure to set post_max_size value slightly bigger than upload size in php.ini file. Dont forget to restart the web service (apache/nginx) after that so the changes will take effect!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you set the wrong php.ini file do this on laravel dd(phpinfo())and look the right php.ini use by laravel in the value : loaded configuration file